# cakephp paginate with group and group count

Tags: cakephp

I have a db table with items with a matching `group_id`. I'd like to display those items in a paginator like this:

```
codeset_id - itemsInGroupCount
group1     -        3
group2     -        6
```

How can I do this? I have the distinct groups but how do I get the count?

My Controller:

```
public function admin_index() {
    $this->Codesetitem->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array(
        'Codesetitem' => array(
            'group' => 'codeset_id',
            'order' => array('codeset_id' => 'asc')
        )            
    );
    $this->set('codesetitems', $this->paginate());
}
```

Comment: Do you really have so many groups that you need pagination?

Comment: I have around 75 groups maybe might be less. But no I don't absolutely need pagination. If there's an easier way to do it please let me know.

Comment: Is there a *belongs to* relationship between groups and items? Do you want to show the groups' names along side item count?

Comment: There was. But I'm thinking for simplicity to screw it and just have 1 table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work on my side:

```
public $components = array('Paginator');

public function index() {
  $this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'fields' => array('Item.group_id', 'COUNT(*) AS "Item.group_count"'),
    'limit' => 3,
    'group' => 'group_id'
  );

  $this->set('items', $this->Paginator->paginate('Item'));
}
```

I simply added `COUNT(*) AS "Foo.bar"` to the `fields` key.

Comment: Then you simply call group_count in your view? Can you show me your view?

Comment: It's a test view. I only print $items with var_dump()